# SQL Server - Invalid Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I am fairly new to SQL and I can't understand why I am receiving an error when establishing foreign keys as I receive an error saying that the destination table is invalid.

Below is the SQL code, any advice on how to fix would be brilliant! :)

The error appears regarding tblFilms and tblCinemaScreens.

```
CREATE TABLE tblCustomer (
    CustomerID int,
    CustomerSurname NVARCHAR(25),
    CustomerForename NVARCHAR(20),
    CustomerAge int,
    CustomerPhoneNumber NVARCHAR(12),
    CustomerEmailAddress NVARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCustomer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerID)
    )
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblBookings (
    BookingID int,
    FilmShowings TIME,
    PriceOfFilm MONEY,
    DateOfBooking DATE,
    FilmID int,
    CinemaScreenID int,
    CustomerID int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblBookings PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (BookingID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FilmID FOREIGN KEY (FilmID) REFERENCES tblFilms(FilmID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerID FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES tblCustomer(CustomerID)
    )
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblFilms (
    FilmID int,
    FilmName VARCHAR(100),
    FilmDuration int,
    AgeRating VARCHAR(3),
    CriticScore int,
    FilmDescription NVARCHAR(300),
    FilmGenre NVARCHAR(20),
    FilmStartScreeningDate DATE,
    FlimEndScreeningDate DATE,
    CinemaScreenID int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblFilms PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FilmID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblFilms FOREIGN KEY (CinemaScreenID) REFERENCES tblCinemaScreens(CinemaScreenID)
    )
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblCinemaScreens (
    CinemaScreenID int, 
    CinemaScreenType NVARCHAR(10),
    NumberOfSeats int,
    FilmID int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCinemaScreens PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CinemaScreenID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblCinemaScreens FOREIGN KEY (FilmID) REFERENCES tblFilms(FilmID)
    )
    GO
```

Comment: You have circular references between `tblFilms` and `tblCinemaScreens`.  I'm not sure this is going to work.

Comment: You can reference a table only if it's exist, first create the tables, then reference them.

Comment: remove the `CinemaScreenID` column from `tblFilms` since a film can be on multiple screens.. then move `tblFilms` to the top of your query and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Cinema screens table does not need a film id and you need to create the tables BEFORE referencing them with FK's

```
CREATE TABLE tblCinemaScreens (
    CinemaScreenID int, 
    CinemaScreenType NVARCHAR(10),
    NumberOfSeats int,
    FilmID int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCinemaScreens PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CinemaScreenID)
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblFilms (
    FilmID int,
    FilmName VARCHAR(100),
    FilmDuration int,
    AgeRating VARCHAR(3),
    CriticScore int,
    FilmDescription NVARCHAR(300),
    FilmGenre NVARCHAR(20),
    FilmStartScreeningDate DATE,
    FlimEndScreeningDate DATE,
    CinemaScreenID int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblFilms PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FilmID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblFilms FOREIGN KEY (CinemaScreenID) REFERENCES tblCinemaScreens(CinemaScreenID)
    )
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblCustomer (
    CustomerID int,
    CustomerSurname NVARCHAR(25),
    CustomerForename NVARCHAR(20),
    CustomerAge int,
    CustomerPhoneNumber NVARCHAR(12),
    CustomerEmailAddress NVARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCustomer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerID)
    )
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblFilms (
    FilmID int,
    FilmName VARCHAR(100),
    FilmDuration int,
    AgeRating VARCHAR(3),
    CriticScore int,
    FilmDescription NVARCHAR(300),
    FilmGenre NVARCHAR(20),
    FilmStartScreeningDate DATE,
    FlimEndScreeningDate DATE,
    CinemaScreenID int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblFilms PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FilmID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblFilms FOREIGN KEY (CinemaScreenID) REFERENCES tblCinemaScreens(CinemaScreenID)
    )
    GO
```

Comment: Im pretty sure that tblCinemaScreens  needs filmId but tblFilms does not need CinemaScreenID

Comment: The cienma screens table has data like number of seats. its information that need not be repeated for every film. It makes more sense to be saying Film A is shown in Screen B than it is Screen A is showing FILM B and to repeat that for every film. Else you end up with say 200 rows in each table, instead of 200 films and X screens.

Comment: Reading your multiple screens for same film comment, you make a good point. did not think of that. Best solution IMO would be a link table between the two :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a foreign key on tables before they are made.  Comment out the lines in the create table statements that are giving you an error and create the tables.  Once the tables are made create the missing foreign keys you need like this:

```
alter table tblFilms
add CONSTRAINT FK_tblFilms FOREIGN KEY (CinemaScreenID) REFERENCES tblCinemaScreens(CinemaScreenID)

alter table tblBookings
add CONSTRAINT FK_FilmID FOREIGN KEY (FilmID) REFERENCES tblFilms(FilmID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change up the schema some to give yourself more flexibility.  I would assume that a film can be on more than one cinema screen so I would take `CinemaScreenID` off of `tblFilms` and remove the foreign key.  You can also remove `FilmID` from `tblBookings` since you have the `CinemaScreenID` already which has the `FilmID`.. Another thing to consider might be having multiple films on the same `CinemaScreen` which would be another tabled called `tblCinemaScreenFilms` and you would put that `CinemaScreenFilmID` on the `tblBookings` instead

```
CREATE TABLE tblFilms (
    FilmID int,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblFilms PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FilmID),
    )
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblCustomer (
    CustomerID int,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCustomer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerID)
    )
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblBookings (
    BookingID int,
    CinemaScreenID int,
    CustomerID int,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblBookings PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (BookingID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CinemaScreenID  FOREIGN KEY (CinemaScreenID ) REFERENCES tblCinemaScreens(CinemaScreenID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerID FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES tblCustomer(CustomerID)
    )
    GO


CREATE TABLE tblCinemaScreens (
    CinemaScreenID int, 
    FilmID int,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCinemaScreens PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CinemaScreenID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblCinemaScreens FOREIGN KEY (FilmID) REFERENCES tblFilms(FilmID)
    )
    GO
```

**Option B (preferred)**

```
CREATE TABLE tblCustomer (
    CustomerID int,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCustomer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerID)
    )
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblFilms (
    FilmID int,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblFilms PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FilmID),
    )
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblCinemaScreens (
    CinemaScreenID int, 
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCinemaScreens PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CinemaScreenID)
    )
    GO


CREATE TABLE tblCinemaScreenFilms (
    CinemaScreenFilmID int,
    CinemaScreenID int, 
    FilmID int
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblCinemaScreenFilms PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CinemaScreenFilmID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FilmID FOREIGN KEY (FilmID) REFERENCES tblFilms(FilmID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CinemaScreenID FOREIGN KEY (FilmID) REFERENCES tblCinemaScreens(CinemaScreenID)
    )
    GO

CREATE TABLE tblBookings (
    BookingID int,
    CustomerID int,
    CinemaScreenFilmID int,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblBookings PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (BookingID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerID FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES tblCustomer(CustomerID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CinemaScreenFilmID FOREIGN KEY (CinemaScreenFilmID) REFERENCES tblCinemaScreenFilms(CinemaScreenFilmID)
    )
    GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is they should have not direct relationships
A film is shown on 0 or more screens

You need a join table

```
rblFilmCinema  
filmID   fk to tblFilms
screenID fk to tblCinemaScreens  

composite PK on filmID, screenID
```

Answer (score -1):

You're creating a table - tblFilms - and adding a foreign key to tblCinemaScreens before the second table has been created.

As a help I usually create all tables and then create any foreign key relationships and other constraints.